# Display/delete component on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, im trying to display my component named documentReader inside div with class desktop-app-grid by clicking and icon below, but icon is also a component, i tried doing this by using state, but i don't know how I can do this. I'm dropping my code below with hope someone can help me.

I got this:

```
    <div className="desktop">
      <div
        className="desktop-app-grid"
      >
        
      </div>
      <div className="taskbar">
        <div className="taskbar-content">
          <div className="apps">
            <TaskbarAppIcon
              appName="documentReader"
              icon={icon}
              title="My CV"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="status">
            <Clock className="clock" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And on click i want to get  displayed in desktop-app-grid like this:

```
<div
        className="desktop-app-grid"
      >
        <documentReader />
      </div>
```

icon.js (code isn't complete)

```
class TaskbarAppIcon extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            clicked: false
        };
        
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick = () => {
    const icon = document.querySelector("img");
    icon.classList.toggle("icon-active");
    setTimeout(() => {
        icon.classList.toggle("icon-active");
    }, 200);
    
    this.setState({
        clicked: true
    });
}
render(){
    const classes = this.props.appName + "Icon icon";
    return (
        <div className={classes} onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <img src={this.props.icon} alt={this.props.appName} title={this.props.title} className="icon-image"></img>
            <div className="isActive"></div>
        </div>
    );
    }
}

export default TaskbarAppIcon;
```

is there any function that works like innerHTML, but isn't a dangerouslyInnerHTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to do is move your handleClick  and clicked state to the parent component where you rendering TaskbarAppIcon. Being more specific where you have this code:

```html
<div className="desktop">
      <div className="desktop-app-grid">
        
      </div>
      <div className="taskbar">
        <div className="taskbar-content">
          <div className="apps">
            <TaskbarAppIcon
              appName="documentReader"
              icon={icon}
              title="My CV"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="status">
            <Clock className="clock" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So for example, the above code is in you App component,  so you need to let it like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      clicked: false,
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    const icon = document.querySelector("img");
    icon.classList.toggle("icon-active");
    setTimeout(() => {
      icon.classList.toggle("icon-active");
    }, 200);

    this.setState({
      clicked: !this.state.clicked,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="desktop">
        <div className="desktop-app-grid">
          // here's the trick, if your clicked state is TRUE it will show <documentReader />
          {this.state.clicked && <documentReader />}
        </div>
        <div className="taskbar">
          <div className="taskbar-content">
            <div className="apps">
              <TaskbarAppIcon
                // Here you are specifying that TaskbarAppIcon has a prop handleClick and its a function
                handleClick={this.handleClick}
                appName="documentReader"
                icon={icon}
                title="My CV"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And in your TaskbarAppIcon component you just need to change

`<div className={classes} onClick={this.handleClick}>`

to

`<div className={classes} onClick={this.props.handleClick}>`

Comment: thanks, it works and that trick is so useful but i didn't know that